# TclError Out of Stack Space Error When Measuring Fonts with Tkinter through Django

Tags: python, django, fonts, tkinter, width

I have a a web interface that users can use to export Excel tables. My server-side code is written in Python/Django. Since I can't autofit the columns without the server actually opening Excel and running it through there, I decided to calculate the width that the columns should be and then resize them based on the calculation using XlsxWriter. This works beautifully, except for one thing: Every once in a while, my export routine will throw a TclError, saying "out of stack space (infinite loop?)". This is the line causing the problem:

```
length = font.measure(s)
```

The line causing the problem within tkFont.py is:

```
return int(self._call("font", "measure", self.name, text))
```

I've been playing around with where to put the Tk initialization, and right now I have it in the root urls.py

Other than that, all I do with it is define a bold font and a normal font, and then use them to measure the width in pixels of a string.

I was reading that Tkinter is not threadsafe so I was trying to ensure that the Tkinter methods couldn't run at the same time, so I made a boolean value initialized to True in settings.py called CANUSETK and I use it to block the measure method from being called while it is set to false. This is just the latest attempt at screwing around to try to get the bloody thing to stop randomly crashing.

**Relevant code:**

In urls.py:

```
settings.TKROOT = tk.Tk()
settings.BOLDFONT = tkFont.Font(family="arial", size=10, weight="bold")
settings.NORMALFONT = tkFont.Font(family="arial", size=10)
```

In the XlsxWriter file containing the class that I use to keep track of column widths as it writes data to the sheet (these methods aren't in the class itself):

```
def measure(font, s): #The font passed here is either the bold or the normal font set up in createFonts()
    while not settings.CANUSETK:
        pass
    settings.CANUSETK = False
    length = font.measure(s)
    settings.CANUSETK = True
    return length

def createFonts():
    while not settings.CANUSETK:
        pass
    settings.CANUSETK = False
    boldFont = settings.BOLDFONT #tkFont.Font(family="arial", size=10, weight="bold")
    normalFont = settings.NORMALFONT #tkFont.Font(family="arial", size=10)
    settings.CANUSETK = True

    return (normalFont, boldFont)
```

Comment: If you sort this out you might consider submitting a simple "autofit" example to XlsxWriter.

Comment: @jmcnamara Yeah for sure.